# Is it possible to collapse several similar nodes of different branches in a hierarchical dimension?

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, dimension

Let's say i have the following hierarchy that i use as a dimension:

- Root
  - A1
    - B11
    - B12
    - ...
    - B1N
    - B1Special
  - A2
    - B21
    - B22
    - ...
    - B2N
    - B2Special
  - ...
  - AM
    - BM1
    - BM2
    - ...
    - BMN
    - BMSpecial

Under each of the "B" nodes there are several more nodes at different levels. Each leaf of the hierarchy has a measure associated (SUM of some fact F).
Is it possible with MDX to have the SUM of all and only the items children of the "Special" nodes?

Comment: Probably, the answer is yes. But I do not understand your requirement: At which of the above nodes do you not want to see the sum of the children? What values do you want to see there? Is 'the SUM of all and only the items children of the "Special" nodes' the sum of all leaf nodes plus the special nodes, i. e. the special nodes are contained twice in the sum?

Comment: Let's say each of the special nodes contains only children that are leaf of the hierarchy. I need the sum of the facts for only these leafs. If i see only the root i want to see a number that is the sum of all facts for the direct children of all the Special nodes. If i expand th first level i want to see the sum of the facts for each of the A nodes and so on.

Comment: Oops, I wrote my answer whilst you were writing your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume you want to see the sum of all 'Special' nodes only once, at the root level. In other words, you want to see just one number in your results set.

Assuming the hierarchy detailed in your original question was called 'Bob', and you had another dimension called 'Kate', you might try this...

```
WITH MEMBER [Bob].[Only the special levels] 
AS 'Aggregate(
   Filter(
      {[Bob].[Name of level which holds B members].members},
      InStr(1, [Bob].CurrentMember.Name, "Special") > 0
   )
)'
SELECT {[Kate].defaultMember} ON ROWS, 
{[Measures].[Whever you want to see aggregated]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Cube name] 
WHERE ([Bob].[Only the special levels])
```

This creates a new, temporary, member in the Bob dimension, which is an aggregation of several other members in the Bob dimension. We start with all the members that sit in one particular level. The `Filter` chooses only those members which have the word "special" in their name.

Note that `InStr` is a VBA function which is supported by Microsoft SSAS. It returns zero if the chosen string is not found. Alternative string searching functions may be available in other flavours of MDX.

You then use this new member in your `WHERE` clause, and slap your other dimensions/measures wherever you want.